# flow control and picture box

Tags: vb.net, bitmap

i can't run the program successfully ,here are my VB codes:

```
Private Sub PictureBox2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox2.Click 

Dim a As Object
a = PictureBox1.Image
Dim b As Object
b = PictureBox2.Image
If a = b Then
    TextBox1.Text = "plz try again~"
Else
    TextBox1.Text = "good jod!"
End If
```

I want the program  to run like this :
When the image in picturebox1 is the same as the picturebox I clicked ,the textbox will show"well down"
but if no,the textbox will show"plz try again"but there's an error shown:`Operator '=' is not defined for type 'Bitmap' and type 'Bitmap'.`

Comment: the error message means what it says.  You cant test bitmap objects that way. where did the images come from?

Comment: the images were from the imagelist

Comment: then use the .Tag property of the PictureBoxes to store the Key or Index of the image used when you assign it; then change the code above to test the Tag.